# SQL Oracle - Find count ratios on ranges from cases

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm basically trying to compute a ratio of people at fault involved in incidents on ranges for every age category. But I'm stuck and can't figure out how to actually compute the ratio from my sub-query where I create the distinct ranges. Here is the snippet I'd like to write - even if it's non-sense. Could anyone help me on this one ? Cheers.

The non-sense stuff is the `from SUBQ` because we get the error `table or view does not exist` and also the `where age_groups = age_groups`. I'm basically trying to make a condition to match with the range I'm grouping in the outer-select clause.

```
select
      age_groups,
      100*trunc(COUNT(*) / (select COUNT(*) from SUBQ where age_groups = age_groups),3) ratio
from
(
   select CASE_ID, AT_FAULT, case
       when PARTY_AGE <= 18 then 'underage'
       when PARTY_AGE > 18 and PARTY_AGE <= 21 then 'young I'
       when PARTY_AGE > 21 and PARTY_AGE <= 24 then 'young II'
       when PARTY_AGE > 24 and PARTY_AGE <= 60 then 'adult'
       when PARTY_AGE > 60 and PARTY_AGE <= 64 then 'elder I'
       else 'elder II'
   end as age_groups
   from PARTY
) SUBQ
where AT_FAULT = 1
group by age_groups
order by 2 desc;
```

NB. The real question is formulated like this : For the drivers of each age groups, find the ratio of cases where the driver was the party at fault. Show this ratio as percentage and display it for every age group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select age_groups,
       100*trunc(Sum(At_Fault)/count(*),3) ratio
from
(
   select CASE_ID, AT_FAULT, case
       when PARTY_AGE <= 18 then 'underage'
       when PARTY_AGE > 18 and PARTY_AGE <= 21 then 'young I'
       when PARTY_AGE > 21 and PARTY_AGE <= 24 then 'young II'
       when PARTY_AGE > 24 and PARTY_AGE <= 60 then 'adult'
       when PARTY_AGE > 60 and PARTY_AGE <= 64 then 'elder I'
       else 'elder II'
   end as age_groups
   from PARTY
) SUBQ
group by age_groups
order by 2 desc;
```

You have to leave out 'where AT_FAULT = 1' because you want to count records where AT_Fault = 0.